# Angular JS | Angular Validation Match Password

Tags: javascript, angularjs, forms, validation, match

I am attempting to use angular-validation-match from https://github.com/TheSharpieOne/angular-validation-match. I am unable to get the match term to trigger to cause any type of form validation. Right now even if the passwords are different it will not show that the passwords do not match. Any reason this may be? Below is the html.

```
  <form name="vm.changeForm"
        ng-submit="vm.changeForm.$valid && vm.attemptChange(password);"
        >
    <md-input-container class="md-block">
      <input required
             type="password"
             placeholder="New Password"
             name="passwordName"
             ng-model="password"
             />
      <div ng-messages="vm.changeForm.passwordConfirm.$error"
           ng-if="vm.changeForm.passwordConfirm.$touched"
           role="alert"
           >
        <div ng-message="required">Please enter a password.</div>
      </div>
    </md-input-container>
    <md-input-container class="md-block">
      <input required
             type="password"
             placeholder="Confirm New Password"
             name="myConfirmField"
             ng-model="passwordConfirm"
             match="password"
             />

      <div ng-show="vm.changeForm.passwordConfirm.$error.match"
           ng-if="vm.changeForm.passwordConfirm.$touched"
           role="alert">Passwords do not match</div>


    </md-input-container>
  </form>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Notes:**

1. You're using ng-if and ng-show on the same `div`, which isn't necessary, you can simply into a simple `ng-if`.
2. You have to use the `name` property instead of the `ng-model`.

So, since your `input` name is *myConfirmField* you must replace this:

```
<div ng-show="vm.changeForm.passwordConfirm.$error.match" ng-if="vm.changeForm.passwordConfirm.$touched" role="alert">Passwords do not match</div>
```

for:

```
<div ng-if="vm.changeForm.myConfirmField.$touched && vm.changeForm.myConfirmField.$error.match" role="alert">Passwords do not match</div>
```

Then you should get the expected result.